# Passing value from ng-repeat to AngularJS with Ionic

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic so this may be a basic question.

I have an HTML file with the following code:

```
<ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-icon-right" href="#/editvenue/{{venueItem.id}}" 
  ng-repeat="venueItem in venue track by venueItem.id">
    <h2>{{venueItem.name}}</h2>
    <p>{{venueItem.phone}}</p>      
    <ionic-ratings ratingsobj='rating'></ionic-ratings>
</ion-item>
```

The  is used to display star ratings using a custom directive. See details here: https://market.ionic.io/plugins/ionicratings. Below is part of the controller in app.js file that includes the code used to generate the stars.

```
    $scope.rating = {
      iconOn: 'ion-ios-star',    
      iconOff: 'ion-ios-star-outline',   
      iconOnColor: 'rgb(255, 215, 0)',  
      iconOffColor:  'rgb(224, 224, 224)',   
      rating: 0,//$scope.venueItem.overallrating, // NEED TO DEFAULT THIS TO A RATING???
      minRating: 0,    
      readOnly: true, // Set to true so user cannot edit rating
      callback: function(rating) {    //Mandatory
        // do nothing as read only stars 
      }
    };
```

I am trying to pass the overallrating value from the current venueItem variable as ng-repeat iterates through the list of venues back to the controller. The goal is to show the star ratings for each venueItem. I am trying to set rating to $scope.venueItem.overallrating but this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add rating object with `ng-repeat` instance

Like this

```
<ionic-ratings ratingsobj='venueItem.rating'></ionic-ratings>
```

Assign this object

```
rating = {
      iconOn: 'ion-ios-star',    
      iconOff: 'ion-ios-star-outline',   
      iconOnColor: 'rgb(255, 215, 0)',  
      iconOffColor:  'rgb(224, 224, 224)',   
      rating: x.overallrating, // NEED TO DEFAULT THIS TO A RATING???
      minRating: 0,    
      readOnly: true, // Set to true so user cannot edit rating
      callback: function(rating) {    //Mandatory
        // do nothing as read only stars 
      }
```

With every object in the list `$scope.venue`

Like this

```
$scope.venue.forEach(function(x){
  x.rating= {
      iconOn: 'ion-ios-star',    
      iconOff: 'ion-ios-star-outline',   
      iconOnColor: 'rgb(255, 215, 0)',  
      iconOffColor:  'rgb(224, 224, 224)',   
      rating: x.overallrating, 
      minRating: 0,    
      readOnly: true, // Set to true so user cannot edit rating
      callback: function(rating) {    //Mandatory
        // do nothing as read only stars 
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: OK I added the function as you noted in my controller and it's now breaking, are you certain the code you provided is the correct syntax? Also, what variable should I be passing to the rating item instead of 0? The correct value is stored in venueItem.overallrating.

Comment: It worked after I removed the ; from the end of the callback function. As well, I used the x.overallrating value to populate the rating item. Thanks!